# Setting "checked" for a checkbox with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, selected, checked

I'd like to do something like this to tick a `checkbox` using **jQuery**:

```
$(".myCheckBox").checked(true);
```

or

```
$(".myCheckBox").selected(true);
```

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: A more specific (and very useful!) question,  "How do I check a item in a checkbox-set BY VALUE?", I think we can also discuss here, and I posted an answer below.

Comment: Check other ways to do this using jQuery here http://stackoverflow.com/a/22019103/1868660

Comment: If you need the onchange event triggered, it's `$("#mycheckbox").click();`

Comment: "Checking something" suggests testing it, so I think 'Making a checkbox checked' is a more clear and better title.

Comment: prop(); function is the perfect answer. See the function definition - http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: attr() doesnot work with IE. using prop() is the best option

Comment: `$(".myCheckBox").prop("checked", true)`

Answer (score 6432, accepted):

### Modern jQuery

Use [`.prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop):

```
$('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', true);
$('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', false);
```

### DOM API

If you're working with just one element, you can always just access the underlying [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) and modify its [`.checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties_checkbox_radio) property:

```
$('.myCheckbox')[0].checked = true;
$('.myCheckbox')[0].checked = false;
```

The benefit to using the `.prop()` and `.attr()` methods instead of this is that they will operate on all matched elements.

### jQuery 1.5.x and below

The `.prop()` method is not available, so you need to use [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr).

```
$('.myCheckbox').attr('checked', true);
$('.myCheckbox').attr('checked', false);
```

Note that this is [the approach used by jQuery's unit tests prior to version 1.6](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.5.2/test/unit/attributes.js#L157) and is preferable to using `$('.myCheckbox').removeAttr('checked');` since the latter will, if the box was initially checked, change the behaviour of a call to [`.reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.reset) on any form that contains it – a subtle but probably unwelcome behaviour change.

For more context, some incomplete discussion of the changes to the handling of the `checked` attribute/property in the transition from 1.5.x to 1.6 can be found in the [version 1.6 release notes](https://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/03/jquery-16-released/) and the **Attributes vs. Properties** section of the [`.prop()` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/prop).

Comment: Yes this is setting the attribute value, and uncheck by removing the attribute. I have updated my answer to show this.

Comment: @Xian removing the the checked attribute makes it impossible to reset the form

Comment: Problem here is if you need something that works for both versions. In that case, you can use the plugin. :) Thanks for the update!

Comment: As a side note, jQuery 1.6.1 should be fixing the issue I mentioned, so we can tehcnically all still go back to using $(...).prop(...)

Comment: "If you're working with just one element, it will always be fastest to use `DOMElement.checked = true`". But it would be negligible, because it's only one element...

Comment: As Tyler says, it is a negligible improvement in performance. To me, coding using a common API makes it more readable than mixing native API and jQuery APIs. I'd stick with jQuery.

Comment: @TylerCrompton - Of course, its not entirely about performance, but doing `$(element).prop('checked')` is a complete waste of typing.  `element.checked` exists and should be used in the cases where you already have `element`

Comment: How can I see prop() in the source code. I tried to search and found these instances but nothing that seems right: https://pix.realquadrant.com/jquery-prop

Answer (score 780):

Use:

```
$(".myCheckbox").attr('checked', true); // Deprecated
$(".myCheckbox").prop('checked', true);
```

And if you want to check if a checkbox is checked or not:

```
$('.myCheckbox').is(':checked');
```

Comment: also $(selector).checked to check is checked

Comment: I tried this exact code and it didn't work for me in the case of a select all / select none checkbox that needs to check and uncheck all as well as check their state. Instead, I tried @Christopher Harris' answer and that did the trick.

Comment: Why using "form #mycheckbox" instead of simply "#mycheckbox"? The id is already unique in the whole document, it is faster and simpler to pick it directly.

Comment: @YuriAlbuquerque it was an example. you can use whatever selector you want.

Comment: $(selector).checked does not work.  There is no 'checked' method in jQuery.

Comment: @BrendanByrd There's a checked property on the DOM object though (without the jQuery wrapping)

Answer (score 359):

This is the correct way of checking and unchecking checkboxes with jQuery, as it is cross-platform standard, and *will* allow form reposts.

```
$('.myCheckBox').each(function(){ this.checked = true; });

$('.myCheckBox').each(function(){ this.checked = false; });
```

By doing this, you are using JavaScript standards for checking and unchecking checkboxes, so any browser that properly implements the "checked" property of the checkbox element will run this code flawlessly. This *should* be all major browsers, but I am unable to test previous to Internet Explorer 9.

**The Problem** (jQuery 1.6):

Once a user clicks on a checkbox, that checkbox stops responding to the "checked" attribute changes.

Here is an example of the checkbox attribute failing to do the job after someone has *clicked* the checkbox (this happens in Chrome).

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xixonia/zgcrB/)**

**The Solution:**

By using JavaScript's "checked" property on the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) elements, we are able to solve the problem directly, instead of trying to manipulate the DOM into doing what we *want* it to do.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xixonia/WnbNC/)

This plugin will alter the checked property of any elements selected by jQuery, and successfully check and uncheck checkboxes under all circumstances. So, while this may seem like an over-bearing solution, it will make your site's user experience better, and help prevent user frustration.

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.checked = function(value) {
        if(value === true || value === false) {
            // Set the value of the checkbox
            $(this).each(function(){ this.checked = value; });
        } 
        else if(value === undefined || value === 'toggle') {
            // Toggle the checkbox
            $(this).each(function(){ this.checked = !this.checked; });
        }

        return this;
    };
})( jQuery );
```

Alternatively, if you do not want to use a plugin, you can use the following code snippets:

```
// Check
$(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);

// Un-check
$(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);

// Toggle
$(':checkbox').prop('checked', function (i, value) {
    return !value;
});
```

Comment: In your first JSFiddle example you should be using `removeAttr('checked')` rather than `attr('checked', false)`

Comment: @DanielXMoore, You're skirting around the issue. The example was to show that once the check-box was clicked by the user, the browser no longer responds to `checked` attribute changes, *regardless* of the method used to change them.

Comment: @ChristopherHarris Ok, you're right, I missed that. As of jQuery 1.6 shouldn't you use the .prop method though?`$('.myCheckBox').prop('checked', true)` That way it will automatically apply to the entire set of matched elements (only when setting though, getting is still only the first)

Comment: Yes. `prop` is definitely the appropriate way to set attributes on an element.

Comment: @ChristopherHarris, I have added what I needed to the plugin to allow some parameter flexibility. This made inline processing easier without the type conversion. Esp from disparate databases with 'ideas' about what "true" is. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cyberjetx/vcp96/

Comment: @JoeJohnston In a perfect world, that shouldn't be built into the plugin. Instead, it should be converted to a true/false value before being using with the plugin. What's to say a database doesn't consider '0' true? It all depends on the database.

Answer (score 166):

You can do

```
$('.myCheckbox').attr('checked',true) //Standards compliant
```

or

```
$("form #mycheckbox").attr('checked', true)
```

If you have custom code in the onclick event for the checkbox that you want to fire, use this one instead:

```
$("#mycheckbox").click();
```

You can uncheck by removing the attribute entirely:

```
$('.myCheckbox').removeAttr('checked')
```

You can check all checkboxes like this:

```
$(".myCheckbox").each(function(){
    $("#mycheckbox").click()
});
```

Comment: you can also go
 $("#myTable input:checkbox").each(...);

Comment: You can also go `$(".myCheckbox").click()`

Comment: @Michah removing the the checked attribute makes it impossible to reset the form

Comment: This answer is out-of-date because it uses `.attr` instead of `.prop`.

Comment: `$("#mycheckbox").click();` worked for me as I was listening to change event too and `.attr` & `.prop` didn't fire change event.

Answer (score 87):

You can also extend the $.fn object with new methods:

```
(function($)  {
   $.fn.extend({
      check : function()  {
         return this.filter(":radio, :checkbox").attr("checked", true);
      },
      uncheck : function()  {
         return this.filter(":radio, :checkbox").removeAttr("checked");
      }
   });
}(jQuery));
```

Then you can just do:

```
$(":checkbox").check();
$(":checkbox").uncheck();
```

Or you may want to give them more unique names like mycheck() and myuncheck()  in case you use some other library that uses those names.

Comment: @livfree75 removing the the checked attribute makes it impossible to reset the form

Comment: This answer is out-of-date because it uses `.attr` instead of `.prop`.

Answer (score 70):

```
$("#mycheckbox")[0].checked = true;
$("#mycheckbox").attr('checked', true);
$("#mycheckbox").click();
```

The last one will fire the click event for the checkbox, the others will not.
So if you have custom code in the onclick event for the checkbox that you want to fire, use the last one.

Comment: top one will fail...checked is not a jquery object member

Comment: This answer is out-of-date because it uses `.attr` instead of `.prop`.

Comment: IMO the `click` event is unreliable in Firefox and Edge.

Answer (score 65):

To check a checkbox you should use

```
 $('.myCheckbox').attr('checked',true);
```

or

```
 $('.myCheckbox').attr('checked','checked');
```

and to uncheck a check box you should always set it to false:

```
 $('.myCheckbox').attr('checked',false);
```

If you do

```
  $('.myCheckbox').removeAttr('checked')
```

it removes the attribute all together and therefore you will not be able to reset the form.

[BAD DEMO jQuery 1.6](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/34vhs/). I think this is broken. For 1.6 I am going to make a new post on that.

[NEW WORKING DEMO jQuery 1.5.2](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/24FLg/) works in Chrome.

Both demos use

```
$('#tc').click(function() {
    if ( $('#myCheckbox').attr('checked')) {
        $('#myCheckbox').attr('checked', false);
    } else {
        $('#myCheckbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
});
```

Comment: This is inaccurate. setting the 'checked' attribute to '' will *not* uncheck check boxes in at least chrome.

Comment: @xixonia I did test before I posted your fiddle doesn't work because you didn't change the menu on the left to include  jquery

Comment: @xixonia thanks again, It seems this doesn't work the same way in jauery 1.6 see note above thanks for adding your solution as well

Comment: mcgralim - in 1.6 its even easier....  `$(".mycheckbox").prop("checked", true/false)`

Comment: @gnarf  thats great but now i'll have to go change that in all my code 8 ^ (

Comment: @mcgrailm - its still not released, but we may be adding some backwards compat for `.attr()` with boolean attributes -- although I wish we wouldn't -- Read: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/prop-attr-rewrite-again

Comment: @Blazemonger do you mean you use .prop rather than .attr ?

Comment: Your answer promised a new up-to-date solution, which you never provided. `.attr` has been the *wrong* approach to this problem for more than two years now.

Comment: I did post a corrected answer at the time but that was 4 years ago dude.  I don't go around updating all my posts and I'm sure most people don't. You down vote was for a post 4 years old saying it's out of date, well duh

Comment: @DaveRager in this case, though, the obsolete answers are not only obsolete, but also completely redundant since the accepted answer covers their content fine already. There's no point in updating an obsolete answer if afterwards it will still not be useful.

Comment: @MarkAmery you mentioned that my post added nothing at the time of post but that is in accurate. If you look at the history of the accepted answer you'll find they suggest removing the element. Which makes it impossible to reset the form, which was why I posted to begin with.

Comment: @mcgrailm I've gone ahead and modified the accepted answer in light of your remarks. If you'd like to cast an eye over it and check that it looks good in its current state, I'd appreciate that. My apologies again for offering up sharp criticism that was, at least in part, highly misguided.

Answer (score 56):

This selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing the given substring "ckbItem":

```
$('input[name *= ckbItem]').prop('checked', true);
```

It will select all elements that contain ckbItem in its name attribute.

Answer (score 51):

Assuming that the question is...

## How do I check a checkbox-set **BY VALUE?**

Remember that in a typical checkbox set, all input tags have the same name, **they differ by the attribute `value`**:  there are no ID for each input of the set.

Xian's answer can be extended with a *more specific selector*, using the following line of code:

```
$("input.myclass[name='myname'][value='the_value']").prop("checked", true);
```

Answer (score 48):

I'm missing the solution. I'll always use:

```
if ($('#myCheckBox:checked').val() !== undefined)
{
    //Checked
}
else
{
    //Not checked
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question (the question is about *setting* whether a checkbox is checked, not determining whether a checkbox is checked). It's also a pretty ugly way of determining if the checkbox is checked (for one thing, you're exploiting the non-self-evident fact that `.val()` will always return `undefined` when called on 0 elements to detect that a jQuery object is empty, when you could simply check its `.length` instead) - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property-using-jquery for more readable approaches.

Answer (score 45):

To check a checkbox using **jQuery 1.6** or higher just do this:

```
checkbox.prop('checked', true);
```

To uncheck, use:

```
checkbox.prop('checked', false);
```

Here' s what I like to use to toggle a checkbox using jQuery:

```
checkbox.prop('checked', !checkbox.prop('checked'));
```

---

If you're using **jQuery 1.5** or lower:

```
checkbox.attr('checked', true);
```

To uncheck, use:

```
checkbox.attr('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 40):

Here is a way to do it without jQuery

```js
function addOrAttachListener(el, type, listener, useCapture) {
  if (el.addEventListener) {
    el.addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture);
  } else if (el.attachEvent) {
    el.attachEvent("on" + type, listener);
  }
};

addOrAttachListener(window, "load", function() {
  var cbElem = document.getElementById("cb");
  var rcbElem = document.getElementById("rcb");
  addOrAttachListener(cbElem, "click", function() {
    rcbElem.checked = cbElem.checked;
  }, false);
}, false);
```

```html
<label>Click Me!
  <input id="cb" type="checkbox" />
</label>
<label>Reflection:
  <input id="rcb" type="checkbox" />
</label>
```

Answer (score 34):

Here is code for checked and unchecked with a button:

```
var set=1;
var unset=0;
jQuery( function() {
    $( '.checkAll' ).live('click', function() {
        $( '.cb-element' ).each(function () {
            if(set==1){ $( '.cb-element' ).attr('checked', true) unset=0; }
            if(set==0){ $( '.cb-element' ).attr('checked', false); unset=1; }
        });
        set=unset;
    });
});
```

Update: Here is the same code block using the newer Jquery 1.6+ prop method, which replaces attr:

```
var set=1;
var unset=0;
jQuery( function() {
    $( '.checkAll' ).live('click', function() {
        $( '.cb-element' ).each(function () {
            if(set==1){ $( '.cb-element' ).prop('checked', true) unset=0; }
            if(set==0){ $( '.cb-element' ).prop('checked', false); unset=1; }
        });
        set=unset;
    });
});
```

Comment: This answer is out-of-date because it uses `.attr` instead of `.prop`.

Answer (score 33):

Try this:

```
$('#checkboxid').get(0).checked = true;  //For checking

$('#checkboxid').get(0).checked = false; //For unchecking
```

Answer (score 31):

We can use `elementObject` with jQuery for getting the attribute checked:

```
$(objectElement).attr('checked');
```

We can use this for all jQuery versions without any error.

Update: Jquery 1.6+ has the new prop method which replaces attr, e.g.:

```
$(objectElement).prop('checked');
```

Comment: This answer is out-of-date because it uses `.attr` instead of `.prop`.

Answer (score 28):

If you are using [PhoneGap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap) doing application development, and you have a value on the button that you want to show instantly, remember to do this

```
$('span.ui-[controlname]',$('[id]')).text("the value");
```

I found that without the span, the interface will not update no matter what you do.

Answer (score 27):

Here is the code and demo for how to check multiple check boxes...

**http://jsfiddle.net/tamilmani/z8TTt/**

```
$("#check").on("click", function () {

    var chk = document.getElementById('check').checked;
    var arr = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    if (chk) {
        for (var i in arr) {
            if (arr[i].name == 'check') arr[i].checked = true;
        }
    } else {
        for (var i in arr) {
            if (arr[i].name == 'check') arr[i].checked = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: -​1; mixing jQuery selectors like `$("#check")` with raw DOM API calls like `document.getElementsByTagName("input")` seems inelegant to me, especially given that the `for` loops here could be avoided by using `.prop()`. Regardless this is yet another late answer that adds nothing new.

Answer (score 23):

Another possible solution:

```
    var c = $("#checkboxid");
    if (c.is(":checked")) {
         $('#checkboxid').prop('checked', false);
    } else {
         $('#checkboxid').prop('checked', true);
    }
```

Answer (score 23):

As @livefree75 said:

**jQuery 1.5.x and below**

You can also extend the $.fn object with new methods:

```
(function($)  {
   $.fn.extend({
      check : function()  {
         return this.filter(":radio, :checkbox").attr("checked", true);
      },
      uncheck : function()  {
         return this.filter(":radio, :checkbox").removeAttr("checked");
      }
   });
}(jQuery));
```

But in new versions of jQuery, we have to use something like this:

**jQuery 1.6+**

```
    (function($)  {
       $.fn.extend({
          check : function()  {
             return this.filter(":radio, :checkbox").prop("checked", true);
          },
          uncheck : function()  {
             return this.filter(":radio, :checkbox").prop("checked",false);
          }
       });
    }(jQuery));
```

Then you can just do:

```
    $(":checkbox").check();
    $(":checkbox").uncheck();
```

Answer (score 20):

For jQuery 1.6+

```
$('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', true);
$('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', false);
```

For jQuery 1.5.x and below

```
$('.myCheckbox').attr('checked', true);
$('.myCheckbox').attr('checked', false);
```

To check,

```
$('.myCheckbox').removeAttr('checked');
```

Answer (score 19):

If using mobile and you want the interface to update and show the checkbox as unchecked, use the following:

```
$("#checkbox1").prop('checked', false).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Answer (score 18):

Be aware of memory leaks in Internet Explorer prior to [Internet Explorer 9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_9), as the [jQuery documentation states](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

> In Internet Explorer prior to version 9, using .prop() to set a DOM
>   element property to anything other than a simple primitive value
>   (number, string, or boolean) can cause memory leaks if the property is
>   not removed (using .removeProp()) before the DOM element is removed
>   from the document. To safely set values on DOM objects without memory
>   leaks, use .data().

Comment: This is irrelevant, since all the (correct) answers use `.prop('checked',true)`.

Comment: Not sure I understood your comment.This still exists in jQuery documentation. Are you implying there is no memory leak in IE < 9 ?

Comment: There is no memory leak in this case, since we *are* setting it to a simple primitive value (Boolean).

Answer (score 18):

To check and uncheck

```
$('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', true);
$('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: -​1; this adds no value at all to an already bloated thread. The code here is exactly the same as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 17):

```
$('controlCheckBox').click(function(){
    var temp = $(this).prop('checked');
    $('controlledCheckBoxes').prop('checked', temp);
});
```

Comment: -​1 for being a code-only answer, not answering the question directly, and adding nothing that other answers hadn't already covered.

Answer (score 16):

This is probably the shortest and easiest solution:

```
$(".myCheckBox")[0].checked = true;
```

or

```
$(".myCheckBox")[0].checked = false;
```

---

Even shorter would be:

```
$(".myCheckBox")[0].checked = !0;
$(".myCheckBox")[0].checked = !1;
```

---

Here is [a *jsFiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/8PCx8/) as well.

Answer (score 15):

Plain JavaScript is very simple and much less overhead:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('myCheckBox');
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
    elements[i].checked = true;
}
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zup4m/)

Comment: @MarkAmery The accepted answer does not cover how to do it without jQuery. My answer adds supplementary benefit to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 15):

When you checked a checkbox like;

```
$('.className').attr('checked', 'checked')
```

it might not be enough. You should also call the function below;

```
$('.className').prop('checked', 'true')
```

Especially when you removed the checkbox checked attribute.

Answer (score 14):

I couldn't get it working using:

```
$("#cb").prop('checked', 'true');
$("#cb").prop('checked', 'false');
```

Both true and false would check the checkbox. What worked for me was:

```
$("#cb").prop('checked', 'true'); // For checking
$("#cb").prop('checked', '');     // For unchecking
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `true` and `false` and not `'true'` and `'false'`?

Comment: It "didn't work" because `'false'` was converted to boolean value which resulted in `true` - empty string evaluates to `false` thus it "worked". See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rDt2P/) for example of what I mean.

Comment: @chris97ong I've rolled back your edit; when someone says "Don't use the code below because it doesn't work", *fixing* that code while leaving the comment saying that it doesn't work is harmful - especially when it breaks the explanation in the comments of *why* the code isn't working. That said, this answer is still somewhat confused and deserves a downvote for the reasons given by tpower and ShadowWizard.

Comment: use true and false values for boolean, do not use 'true' or 'false' (strings).

Answer (score 12):

**Here's the complete answer**
using jQuery

I test it and it works 100% :D

```
    // when the button (select_unit_button) is clicked it returns all the checed checkboxes values 
    $("#select_unit_button").on("click", function(e){

             var arr = [];

             $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
                 arr[i] = $(this).val(); // u can get id or anything else
             });

              //console.log(arr); // u can test it using this in google chrome
    });
```

Answer (score 11):

In jQuery,

```
if($("#checkboxId").is(':checked')){
    alert("Checked");
}
```

or

```
if($("#checkboxId").attr('checked')==true){
    alert("Checked");
}
```

In JavaScript,

```
if (document.getElementById("checkboxID").checked){
    alert("Checked");
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: This answer is out-of-date because it uses `.attr` instead of `.prop`.

Answer (score 11):

In case you use [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework), generate many checkboxes and later have ***to select/unselect all*** using JavaScript you can do the following.

**HTML**

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.CheckBox(string.Format("ProductId_{0}", @item.Id), @item.IsSelected)
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function SelectAll() {       
        $('input[id^="ProductId_"]').each(function () {          
            $(this).prop('checked', true);
        });
    }

    function UnselectAll() {
        $('input[id^="ProductId_"]').each(function () {
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Why is the each needed here?

Answer (score 11):

This may help someone.

HTML5

```
 <input id="check_box" type="checkbox" onclick="handleOnClick()">
```

JavaScript.

```
  function handleOnClick(){

      if($("#check_box").prop('checked'))
      {        
          console.log("current state: checked");
      }
      else
      {         
          console.log("current state: unchecked");
      }    
 }
```

Answer (score 11):

```js
if($('jquery_selector').is(":checked")){
  //somecode
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using `.prop('checked', true|false)` and don’t have changed **checkbox**, you need to add `trigger('click')` like this:

```
// Check
$('#checkboxF1').prop( "checked", true).trigger('click');


// Uncheck
$('#checkboxF1').prop( "checked", false).trigger('click');
```

Comment: so happy that I found this. thank you! almost went nuts!!

Answer (score 9):

```
$(".myCheckBox").prop("checked","checked");
```

Comment: This answer is out-of-date because it uses `.attr` instead of `.prop`.

Answer (score 7):

You can check a checkbox checked condition using JavaScript in different ways. You can see below.

1. First method -
   `$('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', true);`
2. Second method -
   `$('.myCheckbox').attr('checked', true);`
3. Third method (for check condition if checkbox is checked or not) - `$('.myCheckbox').is(':checked')`

Answer (score 6):

You can try this:

```
$('input[name="activity[task_state]"]').val("specify the value you want to check ")
```

Answer (score 6):

**If you happen to be using [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) (perhaps unawarely) ...**

```
$('#myCheckbox').bootstrapToggle('on')
$('#myCheckbox').bootstrapToggle('off')
```

http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/

Answer (score 6):

## Edited on 2019 January

You can use: [**.prop( propertyName )**](https://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName) - *version added: 1.6*

```css
p {margin: 20px 0 0;}
b {color: red;}
label {color: red;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<input id="check1" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<label for="check1">Check here</label>
<p></p>
 
<script>
$( "input" ).change(function() {
  var $input = $( this );
  $( "p" ).html(
    "The .attr( \"checked\" ): <b>" + $input.attr( "checked" ) + "</b><br>" +
    "The .prop( \"checked\" ): <b>" + $input.prop( "checked" ) + "</b><br>" +
    "The .is( \":checked\" ): <b>" + $input.is( ":checked" ) + "</b>" );
}).change();
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

## On Angular Framework

## Example 1

*In your .html file*

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="toggleEditable($event)">
```

*In your .ts file*

```
toggleEditable(event) {
     if ( event.target.checked ) {
         this.contentEditable = true;
    }
}
```

## Example 2

*In your .html file*

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isChecked" (change)="checkAction(isChecked ? 'Action1':'Action2')" />
```

Answer (score 4):

I was wondering why none of the old answers mentioned that to fully simulate the ticking, you also need to simulate the change event if you want to fire something else after simulating ticking:

```
$('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', true).trigger("change");
$('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', false).trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this if you have the id to check it

`document.getElementById('ElementId').checked = false`

And this to uncheck

`document.getElementById('ElementId').checked = true`

Comment: It works, but that's not about jquery.

Answer (score 1):

A JavaScript solution can be also simple and with less overhead:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.myCheckBox').forEach(x=> x.checked=1)
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.myCheckBox').forEach(x=> x.checked=1)
```

```html
checked A: <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox"><br/>
unchecked: <input type="checkbox"><br/>
checked B: <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox"><br/>
```

Comment: This belongs on [Check/Uncheck checkbox with JavaScript (jQuery or Vanilla)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8206565/215552) or [JavaScript check multiple checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31032777/215552), not this jQuery question.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider using vanilla js instead of jquery there is a solution:

```
//for one element: 
document.querySelector('.myCheckBox').checked = true /* or false */ //will select the first matched element
//for multiple elements:
for (const checkbox of document.querySelectorAll('.myCheckBox')) {
checkbox.checked = true //or false
}
```

Answer (score -6):

For overall:

```
$("#checkAll").click(function(){
    $(".somecheckBoxes").prop('checked',$(this).prop('checked')?true:false);
});
```